# How to mock a method that takes an action?

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit

How can I unit test `DoWork` method?

```
public class SomeClass {
  private readonly IClass1 class1;
  private readonly Class2 class2;

  // IClass1 and Class2 are injected in ctor

  public string DoWork() {
    // do some work

    if(this.class2.Method2(() => this.class1.Method1())) {
      return "done!";
    }

    // other work 
  }

}

public interface IClass1 {
  void Method1();
}

public class Class2 {
  public virtual bool Method2(Action action) {
      // return true or false
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to test that class1.Method1() is called once, and the result of DoWork() is "done!"?

Comment: @Jon Ideally, I'd like to make sure `Method2` is called with `Method1` as it's parameter.

Comment: What you should be testing for is the result, not what method was passed on as a parameter. Your unit test should be verifying the result of `DoWork` based on the current state of your class.

Comment: Have a look at my answer with suggestion to use the Moq library

Comment: What exactly do you want to unit test?? What type of mocking framework are you using like Moq or NSubstitute ? the Class2 also should be an Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction) to test the `SomeClass.DoWork` test case that involves `Class2` invoking a member `Method2` that takes an action that invokes `IClass1.Method1`

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeClassTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoWork_Should_Be_Done() {
        //Arrange
        IClass1 class1 = Mock.Of<IClass1>();
        Mock<Class2> class2 = new Mock<Class2>();
        class2.Setup(_ => _.Method2(It.IsAny<Action>()))
            .Returns(true)
            .Callback((Action passedAction) => passedAction?.Invoke());

        SomeClass subject = new SomeClass(class1, class2.Object);
        string expected = "done!";

        //Act
        var actual = subject.DoWork();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected); //actual == expected
        Mock.Get(class1).Verify(_ => _.Method1(), Times.Once); //was action invoked
    }
}
```

Ideally `Class2` dependency sould be abstracted behind an interface

```
public interface IClass2 {
     bool Method2(Action action);
}

public class Class2 : IClass2 {
    //...
}
```

but that is outside of the scope of the original question.

The above test mocks the dependencies and their expected behavior. Variations of that test can be done to cover alternative scenarios that would allow for the complete coverage of that method.

Answer (score 1):

From your code above I see that the injected IClass1 is used just to pass as parameter in injected class2. This is code smell!! The main class SomeClass should not know nothing about Class1.
So I suggest to refactor your code in a way that Class2  will know about Class1 look at the code

```
    public class SomeClass {
    private readonly IClass2 class2;

    public SomeClass(IClass2 class2)
    {
        this.class2 = class2;
    }

    // class1 and class2 are injected in ctor

    public string DoWork() {
        // do some work

        if(this.class2.Method2()) {
            return "done!";
        }

        // other work 

        return string.Empty;
    }

}

public interface IClass1 {
    void Method1();
}

public interface IClass2
{
    bool Method2();
}

public class Class2 : IClass2
{
    private IClass1 class1;

    public Class2(IClass1 class1)
    {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    public virtual bool Method2() {
        // return true or false
        class1.Method1();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then you can easy test it.

```
       [Test]
    public void WhenMethod2ReturnTrue_ThenDoWork_ShouldReturn_Done()
    {
        Mock<IClass2> class2 = new Mock<IClass2>();
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(class2.Object);

        class2.Setup(x => x.Method2()).Returns(true);

        var doWork = someClass.DoWork();

        Assert.That(doWork,Is.EqualTo("done!"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void WhenMethod2ReturnFalse_ThenDoWork_ShouldReturn_Empty()
    {
        Mock<IClass2> class2 = new Mock<IClass2>();
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(class2.Object);

        class2.Setup(x => x.Method2()).Returns(false);

        var doWork = someClass.DoWork();

        Assert.That(doWork,Is.Empty);
    }
```

I've used [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) library for Mocking interfaces